# Pernament: NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: python, django

I try delete object in my app. I get error:

> Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 4}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$delete/(?P\d+)/$']

Below is my code - model, view, url.

In template I have this code:

```
<li>{{ user.name }} | <a href="{% url 'app:delete' pk=user.id %}">Delete</a></li>
```

My standard model with random function:

```
from django.db import models
import random

def random_id():
    r = random.randint(0, 100)
    return r

class User(models.Model):
    rand_id = models.IntegerField(default=random_id)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My view:

```
class Delete(generic.DeleteView):
    """ """

    model = User
    template_name = 'App/confirm.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('app:index'

)
```

My url in app:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.Index.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Delete.as_view(), name='delete'),
)
```

My url in project:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('App.urls', namespace="app")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't terminate the regex with a $ when you're including another urlconf.

```
url(r'', include('App.urls', namespace="app")),
```